# Different Image sizes to support different screen sizes for android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, material-design

I have been trying to understand how to incorporate images in my android application in different fields properly.

**What I understood**

To support differnt screen sizes we have to make like different versions of the same image separately for ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi and so with their respect resolution. From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) I got ldpi should have 120 dpi, mdpi 160 dpi and so. i have also read [here](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) mdpi is like base line and here 1 dpi represents 1 pixel and we can scale our images according to the relationship shared between them, like hdpi is 1.5x mdpi and ldpi is .75x mdpi.

**What I am doing**

For now I am making Images in 1:1 ratio in all the resolution for all different folders of drawable as mentioned [in the first link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and then adding into the application using imageView.
For images in the navigation bar I am making image in the aspect ratio of 16:9 and made a different xml for navigation bar header with its dimensions being `width=match parent and height = ?attr/actionBarSize` Then adding the image through `android:background="source.png"`.

For making the resolutions I have been using GIMP and selecting pixels/inch section.

**DOUBT**

1. is pixel/inch section in GIMP is same as dpi concept or I have taken it entirely wrongly.
2. The approach that I have been taking to add the image (for both normal image and for navigation drawer header), is it correct or should I take another course of action (I have adopted all the above on the basis of my intuition, so I am not confident about my approach).
3. What is the correct way of inserting images in collapsingToolbar, should I go with 16:9 aspect ratio of the image.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Download/Install a plugin for `Android Studio`to do diferent scale images automatically, `Android Drawable Importer`

Comment: @Aspicas  Thanks a lot, That really helped.